# Adding data to CallerID

Tags: ios

I have an app that gives you additional details about the number who's calling you (according to the callerID)

the app records the incoming number, and show on the caller screen the second layer of information.

We're looking to port it into IOS version BUT i have been told that apple will not approve it due to them not allowing people to work on their callerID.

it sounds a bit harsh and i've tried my best to find where it says something about it in the Dev Center but i couldn't find anything - BUT, i couldn't find any reference in their API on how to actually touch the CallerID screen.

i'm a bit puzzled on the subject..  is there anyone who can explain where things are standing ?

Answer (score 0):

Third party apps on iOS have no access to incoming caller id, or call logs.  Your app cannot be written as you have described it.  You'd have to ask the user to type the number in by hand.

Comment: In Android you can use android.content.BroadcastReceiver to monitor for incoming calls and then to fire up toaster...
isn't it possible somehow in IOS ?

Comment: As I said, it is not possible.  iOS does not provide the necessary hooks in public APIs.  You might be able to do it with a jailbreak app, but not something that could be sold on the App Store.